# Prolog: get and append every third item from a list to a new list

Tags: list, prolog

With the following piece of code in Prolog I managed to extract every third item from a list:

```
third([_,_,Z|L], Z).    
third([_,_,C|L], Y) :-
   third(L, Y).
```

However, I still need to append every item that I am extracting to a new list, and finally create a list with only "*every third*" items.
I would appreciate any hint or help!
Thank you.

Comment: What if the list length is not divisible by 3?

Comment: His relation works fine.  Though I'd have used `_C` not `C`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about doing it like this?

```
list_thirds([]        , []).
list_thirds([_]       , []).
list_thirds([_,_]     , []).
list_thirds([_,_,E|Es], [E|Xs]) :-
   list_thirds(Es, Xs).
```

Sample queries using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2:

```
| ?- list_thirds([], Xs).
Xs = [] ? ;
no

| ?- list_thirds([a,b,c], Xs).
Xs = [c] ? ;
no

| ?- list_thirds([a,b,c,d,e,f], Xs).
Xs = [c,f] ? ;
no

| ?- list_thirds([a,b,c,d,e,f,g], Xs).
Xs = [c,f] ? ;
no
```

How about going the "other direction"?

```
| ?- list_thirds(List, [x,y]).
List = [_A,_B,x,_C,_D,y]       ? ;
List = [_A,_B,x,_C,_D,y,_E]    ? ;
List = [_A,_B,x,_C,_D,y,_E,_F] ? ;
no                                     % terminates universally
```

Last, we look at the answer sequence we get from the most general query:

```
| ?- list_thirds(Es, Xs).
Es = []                 , Xs = []      ? ;
Es = [_A]               , Xs = []      ? ;
Es = [_A,_B]            , Xs = []      ? ;
Es = [_A,_B,_C]         , Xs = [_C]    ? ;
Es = [_A,_B,_C,_D]      , Xs = [_C]    ? ;
Es = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E]   , Xs = [_C]    ? ;
Es = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F], Xs = [_C,_F] ? ;
...
```

Comment: In case of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] it responds no. I would expect to give [3,6,9]. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @J.East. Please try again. Better  now?

Answer (score 2):

With SWI-Prolog, and module lambda.pl, you can write

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
third(In, Out) :-
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^(Y=[N,L],
              (   N = 2
              ->  append(L, [X], NL),
              Z = [0,NL]
              ;   N1 is N+1,
              Z = [N1, L])),
          In, [0, []], [_, Out]).
```

With same queries :

```
 ?- third([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], Out).
Out = [3, 6, 9].

  ?- third(X, [3,6,9]).
X = [_G103, _G180, 3, _G352, _G438, 6, _G613, _G699, 9] ;
X = [_G103, _G180, 3, _G352, _G438, 6, _G613, _G699, 9|...] .

 ?- third(X, Y).
X = Y, Y = [] ;
X = [_G87231],
Y = [] ;
X = [_G87231, _G87317],
Y = [] ;
X = [_G87231, _G87317, _G87403],
Y = [_G87403] ;
X = [_G87231, _G87317, _G87403, _G87489],
Y = [_G87403] ;
X = [_G87231, _G87317, _G87403, _G87489, _G87575],
Y = [_G87403] ;
X = [_G87231, _G87317, _G87403, _G87489, _G87575, _G87661],
Y = [_G87403, _G87661] .
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a DCG approach that would also work, analogous to @repeat's answer:

```
thirds([]) --> [].
thirds([]) --> [_].
thirds([]) --> [_,_].
thirds([X|T]) --> [_,_,X], thirds(T).
```

Or more concisely (thanks @repeat):

```
thirds([]) --> [] | [_] | [_,_].
thirds([X|T]) --> [_,_,X], thirds(T).
```

Called as follows:

```
| ?- phrase(thirds(T), [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]).

T = [c,f] ? a
no

| ?- phrase(thirds(T), L).

L = []
T = [] ? ;

L = [_]
T = [] ? ;

L = [_,_]
T = [] ? ;

L = [_,_,A]
T = [A] ? ;

L = [_,_,A,_]
T = [A] ? ;
...
```

Comment: s(X): If you love using bars in DCGs, why not `thirds([]) --> [] |  [_] | [_,_].` ?

Comment: @repeat yeah, that's tidier. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
 bagof(Third,third(List,Third),Result).
```

This collects all items `Third` such that `Third` is third in List; and binds the list of them to `Result`.

For more on bag, see http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3 .

Comment: How about going the other direction, too? Right now, `?- Result = [C,F], bagof(Third,third(List,Third),Result).` runs out of global stack---it does not even give one answer...

Comment: To solve the problem of going the other direction, try:  `findnsols(2,Third,third(List,Third),Result).`

Comment: Does *that* work? I tried `?-  findnsols(2,Third,third(List,Third),Result), false.` but ran out of global stack in a moment...

Comment: Try dropping the `,false`.

Comment: Dropping `,false` doesn't help—it only hides the problem: that goal does not terminate **universally**.

Comment: `nth1(3,List,X), nth1(6,List,Y).`  Anyway, OP's question is answered.

Comment: I don't get it. What is the meaning of *that*? When running the query you gave in your previous comment `?- nth1(3,List,X), nth1(6,List,Y).` I get exactly one answer, `List = [_G606, _G609, X, _G615, _G618, Y|_G622]` ... what is that?

Comment: It is a list in which the 3rd element is X and the 6th is Y, with all other elements and the Rest part of the list, unbound.  So `List` will unify with any list in which the 3rd element is X and the 6th element is Y..

Comment: Now I see that you are doing... You are proposing a specialized code variant tailored to the case `Result = [_,_]`. I don't care about that particular case! The general-case predicate is what I'm interested in. **That** predicate should  work in all directions and have good universal termination behavior!

Comment: If you'd like to ask that as a question, I'm sure someone would like to answer it.  StackOverflow's warning me our discussion is going too long.  I'll honor that.